# Is this email handling service possible with javascript?

Tags: javascript, email

Bear with me for a moment while I try to explain my partner's idea.

I need to build an application that manages emails in the following way:

User A registers and gets an anonymous address. Let's call it `anonymail-one@example.com`

User B does the same. Gets `anonymail-two@example.com`.

User C, D, E, etc.

After some interaction, the program will pair some users, like A with B, C with E, D with A, etc. Then, the program will send them which emails they should correspond to.

So user A will send a message through his personal email (`user-a@gmail.com`) to his pair (`anonymail-five@example.com`). The software will get his message and send it to anonymail-five user (let's say, E).

E will, then, receive a message from `anonymail-one@example.com` in his personal `user-e@gmail.com` account.

Does that makes sense?

So, in short, the app will pair two users that correspond with each other without never knowing who they are without the need to registering new email addresses themselves.

What in earth should I use to start building this? I'm not looking for snippets or code solutions, just directions.

I'm basically a front-end dev, so JS is my main language.

Comment: "What in earth should I use to start building this?" Well, that's entirely up to you. If you know JavaScript best, why not [Node.js](http://nodejs.org)? Note that this question is exceptionally broad and considered off-topic because of that.

Comment: @tadman yeah, I know it's broad. It's meant to be broad because I really have no idea where to start from. The problem is "ah, let's use node" and then get to "node can't do this, I need php, or python, or whatever".

Comment: Node, Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Java, Elixir, you name it it can probably do it. The question is how familiar those are going to feel to you, how difficult it'll be to get in the right mind-set, and which of them is the best fit for your problem. There is no wrong answer here, which is why this is too broad. I suggested Node because you know JavaScript so you'd just need to familiarize yourself with things like [Express](https://expressjs.com) or [Node Mailer](http://nodemailer.com) and how to integrate them.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, you are right. There's no wrong or right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can send email from your javascript code, most of these email service providers provide a javascript SDK you can use in your code to send email from your Javascript code. I have done that with [mandril](http://mandrillapp.com/) before. This is not safe though as you would need to store your API KEY and other secret keys on the client side. So basically, anyone can read your source code

Comment: Suggesting something that "works" but involves handing over secret API keys is really not a solution at all.